# The view urlshort.views.page_redirect didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I'm making a url shortener with django. I have a form that has a long_url attribute. I'm trying to get the long_url and add it to a redirect view with a HttpResponseRedirect.

```py
# Form
from .models import ShortURL
from django import forms

class CreateNewShortURL(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=ShortURL

        fields = {'long_url'}

        widgets = {
            'long_url': forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }


# View
def page_redirect(request, url):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CreateNewShortURL(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            original_website = form.cleaned_data['long_url']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(original_website)
```

When I go to the link, it gives me `The view urlshort.views.page_redirect didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not returning because there is no valid form, you need to redirect to a form for the user to enter data first, you will then get that data from the form to perform your redirect. additionally because a user is returning data you will need to get the data from request.POST.

```
def page_redirect(request, url):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CreateNewShortURL(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            original_website = form.cleaned_data['long_url']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(original_website)
    return render(request,'template') # this is the form for the user to enter the url
```